# Notify to other application instance running on different machine

Tags: python, django, crossbar

I am running Django application on multiple machines say m1, m2, m3.

all of them are using centralized database hosted on `my_db_host.com`.

I want to notify to m2, m3 instances from m1 on particular action/activity.

I have explored [crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/), but could not find proper guideline to integrate this.

Please let me know what is the best approach for message passing from one app-instance to other.

Comment: Have you looked at Celery?

Comment: this is kind of "Task Queue", and I need to send message to running application instance.

Comment: Aren't you describing a message queue? Take a look at [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html). Doesn't this solve your problem?

Comment: @rkp yep and thats what Celery and a message broker is for i.e. RabbitMQ

Comment: @GlynJackson I want real-time update, so that other app(hosted on different machine) could reload its objects(present in memory) from database.

Comment: @rkp passing messages is what a broker does! We have systems which run tasks then inform other process one action is complete to start another processing them parallel (parallel distribution). Your question seems like you need Celery Chords, Chains and Callbacks  http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/tasksets.html not Sockets. If you do need sockets start here: http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/

Comment: Crossbar.io is a message broker that implements Publish & Subscribe, but also Routed RPC. So you can have components m2/m3 be notified from m1. The problem is: Django is a WSGI app, and WSGI is an inherently blocking API. It is hard to wait on one thing (notification from m1) while still doing useful work - on the same WSGI worker thread/process.